# Debug Assertion Failed on \$InstallDir\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\olelock.cpp line 62 on MFC programming

Tags: c#, c, wpf, mfc

I have to call a sample MFC view in C# application, using Visual Studio 2012. I use C++/CLI project and call C++ class from C#. To do this I have to use this line of code

```
AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
```

This will call the resource handle of MFC DLL resource instead of default resource (exe file on C#). The MFC view runs OK, but it appears an exception (as C message box):

```
 Debug Assertion Failed on  \$InstallDir\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\olelock.cpp line 62
```

Here is the source code I checked on install Dir:

```
void AFXAPI AfxOleUnlockApp()
{
    AFX_MODULE_STATE* pModuleState = AfxGetModuleState();
    ASSERT(pModuleState->m_nObjectCount != 0);
    if (InterlockedDecrement(&pModuleState->m_nObjectCount) == 0)
    {
        // allow application to shut down when all the objects have
        //  been released
        ::AfxOleOnReleaseAllObjects();
    }
}
```

How can I avoid this assertion? Thank you for your support.

Comment: When does the assertion occur? At shutdown? At Startup? After the MFC View is Shown?

Comment: after the MFC View is shown. In this case, the view is shown in the a Grid in WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Assertion simply says that you called AfxOleUnlockApp more often than AfxOleLockApp as called.

Set breakpoints to the specific functions. Check who calls lock/unlock. Probably there are objects freed more than once...